# How to fix repeating canvas.toBuffer or canvas.createPdfStream content

Tags: node-canvas

I'm using canvas.toBuffer in a loop to generate pdf for different content but all the generated pdf's have the same content. Below is a snippet of the loop I'm using.

```js
for (const d of data) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    context.fillText(d.name.toUpperCase(), 1685, 1556);
    fs.writeFileSync(`./assets/certs/${d.email}.pdf`,canvas.toBuffer());
}
```

**data** is of type, `Array<{name:String, email:String}>`.
The name is supposed to print the name of each user on an image but It turns out all the pdfs generated have just the name of the first user.

I tried creating a ReadStream from the canvas but I end up with the same issue. Is there something I'm doing wrong or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a bug in node-canvas. It's not possible to reuse a PDF or SVG canvas after calling `toBuffer()` on it (https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1195).

As a work-around, you can make a new canvas in each iteration of the loop.